# How to remove external users from document library folder in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

In our document library there was folders which is shared with external users using `outlook.com` accounts. How do I see and remove these users from folder level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the library.

- Right beside the folder should be three dots. Clicking on them will open a new menu.
- Again there are three dots that will open another menu. Here you can choose "View properties".
- In the following screen click on "Shared with" on the top menu.
- Last but not least click on "Advanced" and you will get to the permission-menu for this folder.
- Be aware that the permissions inherit from the parent level.

Comment: i went to share with and found the user's who are inside our office but i can't see the external users in there and when i click advanced within the same window i can see on top "There are limited access users on this site. Users may have limited access if an item or document under the site has been shared with them. "Show users".
This folder has unique permissions" i clicked on show users to see some external users to whom i have shared the folder but not all.

Comment: before sharing do i have to add these external users in central admin or some were ?

Comment: I found out, that the rules with microsoft accounts are a bit different. As you can see here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138336/deleting-external-users-from-sharepoint-online

Comment: i refered the link but i cant seems to find the below option in the central admin. Go to Admin > Service Settings > sites and document sharing.
Click Remove individual external users.
Select the external users you want to remove, and then click Delete (the trash can icon).

Comment: Did you try the second link the user provided?

http://blogs.technet.com/b/french_sharepoint_gbs_blog/archive/2014/12/17/how-to-delete-a-problematic-external-user-account-from-a-sharepoint-online-site-users-list.aspx